# The Fruit of the Spirit

Tags: galatians, pauline-epistles

Galatians 5:22-23 ([NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Galatians%205:22-23&version=NIV)),

22 But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, forbearance, kindness, goodness, faithfulness, 23 gentleness and self-control. Against such things there is no law.

Is the list given above exhaustive? Or are there other spiritual fruit available and producible in the life of the Christian believer?

I am thinking Paul could have, for example, listed things like holiness, courage, and etc.

Comment: These are the fruits of Him who is The Holy Spirit. His presence (within) is the holiness from which the fruits proceed. So each one of the fruits may be, each, seen as an holy fruit. Courage is associated with faith, usualy.

Answer (score 3):

Human language is imperfect and ambiguous, so different virtues overlap sometimes, or at least their fringes embrace each other; and there are many shades of smilingly one and the same virtue, so that even more nuanced language and terms can be invented to express them (like "compassion" and "empathy" are nearly the same but perhaps not entirely the same); and sometimes one language is more apt to express certain shade of a notion than another.

But the general principle can be drawn from James 1:17: "Every good gift and every perfect gift is from above, coming down from the Father of lights"; thus, since the Father of Lights dispenses His riches and goodness to us through the Holy Spirit, thus anything good and divine you can think of or name can be freely ascribed to the Holy Spirit and thus neither Paul's mentioned list is exhaustive, unless he intended (which I doubt to be the case) to name all general virtues of which all other virtues would be nuances and variations (for instance the "holiness" mentioned by you a variation of "faithfulness" for the second is the cause of the first, for we are made holy by being faithful to His commandments).

Comment: "their fringes embrace each other" - What a beautiful phrase!

Comment: @PieterRousseau Thanks for the kind words! This phrase came to my mind somehow unexpectedly in the attempt to express the idea.

Answer (score 1):

**The Fruit of the Spirit**

Galatians 5:22-23 (NIV),

> 22 But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, forbearance,
> kindness, goodness, faithfulness, 23 gentleness and self-control.
> **Against such things** there is no law.

The expression **“such things”** implies that the fruitage of God's spirit is not limited to the nine features listed here. The Christian personality is made up of these and other qualities, all of which are produced with the help of the holy spirit.​ **Compare below.**

Ephesians 4:24,32 NASB

> 24 And put on the new [a]self, which [b]in the likeness of God has
> been created in righteousness and holiness of the truth   32 Be kind
> to one another, tender-hearted, forgiving each other, just as God in
> Christ also has forgiven [a]you..

Colossians 3:12-15 NET

Exhortation to Unity and Love

> 12 Therefore, as the elect of God, holy and dearly loved, clothe
> yourselves with a heart of mercy,[a] kindness, humility, gentleness,
> and patience, 13 bearing with one another and forgiving[b] one
> another, if someone happens to have[c] a complaint against anyone
> else. Just as the Lord has forgiven you, so you also forgive
> others.[d] 14 And to all these[e] virtues[f] add[g] love, which is the
> perfect bond.[h] 15 Let the peace of Christ be in control in your
> heart (for you were in fact called as one body[i] to this peace), and
> be thankful.

James 3:17-18 NKJV

> 17 But the wisdom that is from above is first pure, then peaceable,
> gentle, willing to yield, full of mercy and good fruits, without
> partiality and without hypocrisy. 18 Now the fruit of righteousness is
> sown in peace by those who make peace.